# JComboBox: кнопка в выпадающем списке для выбора элемента

Tags: java, swing, gui, combobox

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь сделать следующее: имеется экземпляр `JComboBox`. При нажатии на него выпадает список неких элементов. Мне нужно чтобы под списком элементов (именно под, а не в нем самом) также появлялась кнопка.

Для чего нужна эта кнопка: в выпадающем списке содержатся картинки. Добавляться новые картинки должны следующим образом: при нажатии на кнопку открывается выбор фалов, пользователь выбирает на своем компьютере нужное изображение и оно заносится в экземпляр `JComboBox`.

Как отображать картинки в `JComboBox`, реализовать выбор файла - я разобрался. Но не могу добавить кнопку так, чтобы она находилась не в списке картинок, а под ним и к тому же была активной.

Пожалуйста подскажите как это можно сделать.

Comment: Добавьте код разметки Вашего `comboBox` что бы проще было Вам помочь.

Comment: Простите, я не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду под разметкой. Для задания внешнего вида приложению я не использую языки разметки, поскольку swing их не поддерживает. Все задается в java коде.

Comment: Извините, неверно сформулировал. Имел ввиду что сам код можно вынести на обозрение?

Comment: Вот тут решение. Учись пользоваться поиском на английском:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098521/how-to-put-a-jbutton-inside-a-jcombobox

Comment: Спасибо, Николай Беляков. Это почти то, что нужно. Единственное - кнопка добавляется в сам список, а это значит, что если пользователь будет прокручивать элементы в списке, то и кнопка будет прокручиваться вместе с ними. Мне же надо чтобы она была отделена от списка, находилась ПОД ни, а не В нем.

Comment: Попробуйте в пейнте нарисовать, что Вы хотите получить. На пальцах чтоб не объяснять)